# PyCharm How to import module from network share

Tags: pycharm

I'm running PyCharm 2.7.2 on Windows7 with interpreter v2.7.4

I need to import a module that lives on a network share. I believe the PyCharm way of doing this is to add another 'Content Root'. However PyCharm only presents the C drive in the Add Content Root dialog. How can I import the module? (without moving it or messing with pythonpath at runtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm doesn't support UNC paths, as a workaround you can map this share to a network drive letter and PyCharm will see it.

Note that it may affect performance. If running as Administrator, Windows will not allow the application to access any network drives.

Comment: The drive is already mapped to a letter but only C is shown in the dialog. I'm not running as Admin.

Comment: In this case I don't see any reason why the drive is not visible. Try rebooting and double check PyCharm is not started as Admin.

Comment: Drives appeared after a reboot. Thanks.

Comment: This worked with windows 7. I do not see the network drives on Windows 8. I am using Pycharm 4.0.4